# Apache DBCP BasicDataSource validation query spamming database

Tags: jdbc, database-connection, activemq-classic, apache-commons-dbcp

I am running Apache ActiveMQ, with a database backing it. As a datasource, Apache DBCP BasicDataSource is used.

BasicDataSource has a configuration for `validationQuery`, used to check the database connection.

What I am noticing is that this query is run really often, ~6000 times per minute (once every 10ms). I find this to be a bit uneccessary, so I'm wondering if it is possible to configure the interval of running the validation query.

If not possible, any pointers as to a replacement that supports this and runs with ActiveMQ would be appreciated.